# Ruby on Rails routing: how to remove (using redirection) a URL prefix

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, redirect, routes

I'm sure this is dead simple, which is why I'm so annoyed...

The problem originated from using [translate_routes](https://github.com/raul/translate_routes/). This is very simple to use and presents no problem whatsoever. All I want is to be able to have the default locale prefix in the url, optionally.

Right now, I can do:

`GET /controller/` and

`GET /fr/controlleur/`, but trying

`GET /en/controller/` fails.

I figured that the `en` in the last example is not useful, so I want to 'remove' it using redirection. However, all my attempts up till now have failed.

How can I remove that prefix?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
match "/en/*path" => redirect("/%{path}")
```

- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#redirection
- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#route-globbing